# Two consecutive side menus with Ionic Framework

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

Using IonicFramework it's possible to open a second submenu from a ion-side-menu?

[image: menu opened]

[image: submenu opened]

Comment: Hi, how did you do it? I am trying to make the same menu but I have not found how :((

Answer (score 1):

I know about a similar behavior:
You can see the demo here:
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tcIGK
Or this one, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eCKkm (it's a second menu level)

Basically, works with the default side menu, but when swipe to the right, the menu appears and each one could have an independent sub menu/form, ect., without continue the navigation.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('eventmenu', {
          url: "/event",
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
        })
        .state('eventmenu.home', {
          url: "/home",
          views: {
            'menuContent' :{
              templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
            }
          }
        })
        .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
          url: "/check-in",
          views: {
            'menuContent' :{
              templateUrl: "templates/check-in.html",
              controller: "CheckinCtrl"
            }
          }
        })
        .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
          url: "/attendees",
          views: {
            'menuContent' :{
              templateUrl: "templates/attendees.html",
              controller: "AttendeesCtrl"
            }
          }
        })
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make the same menu,
could you explain me a little?
I have it this way  and settings has 3 options, how could I put them?:     this.appPages.push({
      title: 'Settings',
      url: '/settings',
      color: 'gray-light'
    })